# create a web application using Flask but no outpu

Tags: python, flask

I tried to build a Flask application on Windows 10, following the steps listed in the book "Flask Web Development: Developing Web Applications with Python, Second Edition" authored by Miguel Grinberg.

I used the Command Prompt to do the steps.

Step 1: Create a Project Directory, say "cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop\its"

Step 2: set up a virtual environment, then a file folder named "venv" appears within the project directory

Step 3: activate the virtual environment

Step 4: Installed Flask

Step 5: Create and Run the Flask Application with code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I saved the file in the directory "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\its\venv" and named it as app.py

Step 6: Run the code using the command "python app.py" in the command prompt, but here it's odd as there is no output.

have tried "http://localhost:5000/" in Google Chrome, but nothing but information "This site can’t be reached; localhost refused to connect."

Any thoughts about this? Thanks for your help

want to view the "Hello World!" message in the web browser using the Flask application

Comment: Check to see if another application is using port 5000 by : **netstat -ano**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have checked using the command you provided. It appears that there are several active connections on my system, but none of them are using port 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your question, I think you at first should follow the official docs of flask regarding this point --> [enter link description here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/)

Which tell you how to start your app
You couldn't use just `python app.py` as long as you're demonstrate a flask app just use `python -m flask --app app run` or just `flask --app app_name run` and in your case you've named your app app.py so you don't have to write the previous command you just go with `flask run` command.

This should be already after activating the virtenv

Answer (score -1):

It's been solved.

Orignally the app.py was written in Jupyter notebook and saved. There are many lines I coundn't understand while opening the file.

So I used Python IDLE shell to write and save the file, then it worked.

Thanks. @Mahmoud Samaha @Achraf Ben Salah